# Error when trying to reference a github repository

Tags: node.js, git, angular, npm, primeng

I am using angular 2 and I am trying to reference a github repo directly instead of an npm package in order to debug but the project does not compile.
In my packages.json I changed `"primeng": "4.2.2",` with `"primeng": "git+https://github.com/primefaces/primeng.git"`

When I build I get following errors

```
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./node_modules/famfamfam-flags/dist/sprite/famfamfam-flags.css ./node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css ./node_modules/jquery.uniform/dist/css/default.css ./node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.css ./node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css ./node_modules/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css ./node_modules/jtable/lib/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css ./node_modules/morris.js/morris.css ./node_modules/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css ./node_modules/bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css ./src/app/shared/core.less ./src/app/shared/layout/layout.less ./src/assets/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css ./node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css ./src/styles.css ./src/fonts.css ./src/Test-palette.css ./src/app/risk-management/styles/module-styles.css ./src/primeng-chips.css ./src/primeng-datatable.css ./src/primeng-multiselect.css ./src/primeng-sidebar.css ./src/animations.css ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/redmond/theme.css ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css ./node_modules/loaders.css/loaders.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\SourceControl\Test\TestProject\src\TestProject.Client\node_modules\primeng\resources\primeng.min.css'
```

When I check the node modules/primeng I only see these files:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the npm ignore file they must have ignored the src files in the npm ignore so you are not getting it in the node modules files

Comment: I corrected toir tagging! Please remember!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM `primeng` package was built for distribution and has `resources` directory, while Github repository contains only source files. This is very common among NPM packages.

Since Github repo source is used for the purpose of debugging, the solution is to build the package manually. Considering that resources are built [with Gulp](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/4.2.2/gulpfile.js#L48) and [not generic NPM `build`](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/4.2.2/package.json#L8) script, it should be something like:

```
cd ./node_modules/primeng
npm i
gulp build-assets
```

Comment: I run node_modules\primeng>gulp build-assets
[17:27:45] No gulpfile found

Comment: @pantonis Check with your eyes if current working directory is right . gulpfile.js should be there.

Comment: I referenced primeng as described above. I then go to node_modules of my project where I see the files that I posted above in the screenshot I run npm i and after packages are downloaded I don't see any gulpfile.js

Comment: @pantonis Notice that gulpfile.js is ignored as well, https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/4.2.2/.npmignore#L51 . Consider cloning the repo directly to node_modules instead, or forking and un-ignoring all files that are crucial for building.

Comment: @estus after cloning the repo  as you suggested into the the node_modules do I need to run anything or I just build my project?

Comment: @pantonis You still need to run `npm i` and `gulp build-assets` as described above. I'd expect that this would be enough.

Comment: @estus I did both but still the same error. When I go to the css path I dont see css but rather the scss file.

Comment: @pantonis I cannot confirm this. scss files are in `src`. After running `gulp build-assets` `node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css` is there, as expected. Make sure you did not have errors when running gulp.

Comment: I did not have any errors. I also see other errors such as ```/node_modules/primeng/primeng"' has no exported member 'DataTable'.```

Comment: @estus I managed to build scss files and now I am getting errors such as : ```/primeng/primeng"' has no exported member 'DataTable'. has no exported member 'ChipsModule'.``` and many others

Comment: @pantonis I guess that's because JS part of the package is not built. Try also run `npm build`.

Comment: @estus I tried npm build nothing happened then ng build it finished successfully but then I get the same errors

Comment: @pantonis Typo, `npm run build`. Hope this will work for you. Any way, that's what we do in such situations in general, run all build scripts to get a package in the state it was published to NPM. I cannot confirm how good it works for Ngprime since I don't use it.

Comment: @estus After running the above command I get a dist folder with module.chunk.js and module.chunk.js.map files only. But stll the same errors. What should be the expected output of the command above?

Comment: @pantonis I'd expect JS files like `primeng\components\accordion\accordion.js` to appear alongside with `primeng\components\accordion\accordion.ts`. But it looks to me that build script doesn't do that, and I'm not sure what's the problem. If you have problems with building it as it was intended, I'd suggest to open an issue in package repo because this may be a bug (the fact that the package cannot be fully built with `npm run build` suggests that the maintainers didn't care too much if it can be built properly by the community).

Comment: @pantonis You're welcome. This approach works out of the box for virtually any project out there because devs are human beings and have to build it somehow in order to publish to NPM. Too bad it didn't work in this case.

Comment: @estus this library is not famous for its reliability :D

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `github.com` prefix there, this should be enough:

`"primeng": "primefaces/primeng"`

More about this here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls

Problem is that the `resources` folder is ignore via `.gitignore`. There is a `gulpfile.js`, that is responsible for creating it. You could run that manually if you want to use github version directly.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/gulpfile.js